# Polarisation inside a sphere

Tags: electric-fields

Why is the electric field inside a uniformly polarised sphere not zero?
I am confused because charge enclosed is zero and by Gauss' law electric field has to be zero.

Comment: Indeed, the flux of the electric field on a closed surface completely contained inside the sphere is zero. This is the requirement by Gauss' law, the electric field could be different from zero, as it is in this case.